# What does this comment mean?

Tags: meaning

This YouTube comment has tons of likes. What does it mean?

From [Aladdin - Official Trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JcMtWwiyzpU)

> Aladdin: Genie... I wish for you to make me a prince
>
> Genie: would you like to be a fresh one?...(looks at camera)

Comment: It's referring to the Fresh Prince of Bel Air, who was played by Will Smith.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a slang usage of *fresh*.

> **fresh**
>
> 5 slang : fashionable, cool
>
> https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fresh

This slang use of *fresh* is not very current.  You won't hear too many people using *fresh* like this in 2019.

But a lot of people used *fresh* to mean *cool* in the 1990s when Will Smith, the actor who plays the genie, starred in a popular TV sitcom called *The **Fresh Prince** of Bel-Air*.

Answer (score 1):

It's a joke that relies on familiarity with a cultural reference.

Much of the audience will be familiar with a popular television show titled *[Fresh Prince of Bel-Air](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Fresh_Prince_of_Bel-Air)*.  It starred [Will Smith](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Will_Smith) as a street-smart teenager (the titular 'Fresh Prince', which previously had been [a stage name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DJ_Jazzy_Jeff_%26_The_Fresh_Prince) for Smith, who plays the Genie in the film) who is sent from West Philadelphia to live with wealthy relatives.

Both the wish by Alladin in the movie and the Will Smith television show incorporate the [rags to riches](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RagsToRiches) trope.